# MSAL Angular Preview for up to 5 only

Tags: azure-ad-msal

MSAL Angular framework is out for preview. It states it only up to Angular 5, does this mean its not compatible with Angular 6? If not is there any ETA for Angular 6 support?

Comment: Because of this I made a package that support Angular6+ and uses msal 1.0.0.:  https://github.com/Marcelh1983/angular-msal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [MSAL Angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular) in the app build with Angular 7, so you should be able to use it with Angular 6.

Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/421) about providing compatibility with Angular 6+.

**UPDATE**

[Support for Angular is planned for July-Sep 2019](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki#roadmap)